# Getting a crease when using a Mirror Modifier

Tags: modeling

I'm *trying* to model a spaceship and I ran into this weird predicament. I'm using a mirror modifier as can be seen and I get this annoying crease:
[image]

If I enter edit mode, you can see that the verticies are connected:
[image]

And adding mean crease doesn't fix much:
[image]

What's a good way to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have some non-manifold inside faces caused by the mirroring. Select and delete them with <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd>.

[image]